# Libraries wrapping Python threads

Tags: python

What libraries exist that provide a higher level interface to concurrency in Python?  I'm not looking to necessarily make use of multiple cores - if the GIL serializes everything, that's fine with me.  I just want a smoother/higher level interface to concurrency.

My application is writing tests of our software, and sometimes I'd like to, say, run several simulated users, as well as code that makes changes to the backend, all in parallel.  It would be great if, say, I could do something like this:

```
setup_front_end()
setup_back_end()
parallel:
   while some_condition():
      os.system('wget http://...')
      sleep(1)
   for x in xrange(10):
      os.system('top >> top.log')
      sleep(1)
   for x in xrange(100):
      mess_with_backend()
```

The idea in the above code is that we start 3 threads, the first one runs:

```
while some_condition():
   os.system('wget http://...')
   sleep(1)
```

The second one runs the second loop, and the third one runs the third.

I know it won't be that simple, but is there something that can take the drudgery out of writing functions, spinning up threads, joining on them, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `threading` module, you should also have a look into the [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures) module (for py2 ther is a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures)).

It provides ready to use thread/process pool implementations and allows you to write efficient concurrent code. As it provides an uniform API for threading and multiprocessing it allows you to switch easily between the two, should you ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the complexity of creating a Thread and setting the parameters, create a simple decorator and use it for your functions:

async.py:

```
from threading import Thread
class async(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread(target=self.func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
```

This is just a very simple wrapper around your functions which creates a new Thread and executes the function in the Thread. If you want, you can easily adapt this to use processes instead of threads.

main.py:

```
import time
from async import async

@async
def long_function(name, seconds_to_wait):
    print "%s started..." % name
    time.sleep(seconds_to_wait)
    print "%s ended after %d seconds" % (name, seconds_to_wait)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    long_function("first", 3)
    long_function("second", 4)
    long_function("third", 5)
```

Just decorate your functions with `@async` and you can call it asynchronously.

In your case: Just wrap your loops within a function and decorate them with `@async`.

For a full feature asynchronous decorator look at: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Asynchronous_Call